# How to programmatically set an Angular JS select value in a web crawler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The gotcha is that I do not have the codebase, I just want a quick function that selects my predefined values in ~150 dropdown select fields. It seems that simple value assign does not work:

```
document.getElementById('myId').value = 'myValue';
```

It seems that this way angular change detection is not triggered. Visually all fields are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new dom [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) and use [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to trigger it on each element you set value on.

Demo:

```js
/// Outside angular app
const newVals= [
  {id:'sel1', val :'1'},
  {id:'sel2', val :'2'},
];

const setValue = ({id, val})=>{
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.value = val;
    console.log('Triggering change on id =', id)
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
}

// delay to let angular render
setTimeout(() => {
  newVals.forEach(setValue)
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">

  Sel1 :
  <select id="sel1" ng-model="$ctrl.sel1" ng-change="$ctrl.logChange($ctrl.sel1)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  Sel2 :
  <select id="sel2" ng-model="$ctrl.sel2" ng-change="$ctrl.logChange($ctrl.sel2)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  // Angular App
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    this.logChange = (val) => {
      console.log('Angular change event triggered, new value =', val)
    }
  });
</script>
```